# AD Server 2012 - Make an admin account that can only add new users

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I have been looking all over the web trying to find an answer but no luck.

Does anybody know, if it's possible, how to make an admin account, that ONLY have access to add in new users to the Active Directory??
The account does not need to have a computer or anything, it just needs to be able to add new users to the AD.
We are running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Delegation of Control Wizard to assign special permissions.

The following different permissions can be set with one click::

- Create, delete an manage user accounts
- Reset user passwords and force password change at next logon
- Read all user informaiton
- Create, delete and manage groups
- Modify the membership of a group
- Manage Group Policy links
- Generate Resultant Set of Policy (Planning and Logging)
- Create, delete and manage inetOrgPerson acocounts
- Reset inetOrgPerson password an force password change at next logon
- Read all inetOrgPerson information

[Here is a example.](http://www.windows-server-2012-r2.com/using-the-delegation-of-control-wizard.html)

Comment: Awesome, that worked flawlessly. I was  a bit unsure of what choice to pick, but I choose "Create, delete and manage user acounts" and it worked